# Print elements of a list in the same line

Tags: list, haskell

I'm new at haskell and  I'm trying to print the elements of a list in a same line . For example:

```
[1,2,3,4] = 1234
```

If elements are Strings I can print it with `mapM_ putStr ["1","2","3","\n"]` 
but they aren't.. Someone knows a solution to make a function and print that?

I try `dignum xs = [ mapM_ putStr x | x <- xs ]` too buts don't work ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `show :: Show a => a -> String` to convert an element (here an integer), to its textual representation as a `String`.

Furthermore we can use `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]` to convert a list of lists of elements to a list of elements (by concatenating these lists together). In the context of a `String`, we can thus use `concat :: [String] -> String` to join the numbers together.

So we can then use:

```
printConcat :: Show a => [a] -> IO ()
printConcat = putStrLn . concat . map show
```

This then generates:

```
Prelude> printConcat [1,2,3,4]
1234
```

Note that the `printConcat` function is *not* limited to numbers (integers), it can take any type of objects that are a type instance of the `Show` class.

Comment: Thanks!! Solved !